# Parallel Evaluation of Cloudpickle object using Joblib

Tags: python-3.x, pickle, sympy, joblib

I would like to evaluate a cloudpickle object (created from sympy's lambdify) using multiple cores on my machine. Below is a minimal example of what I am trying to do.

```
import sympy as sy
import cloudpickle
from joblib import Parallel, delayed

x, y = sy.symbols("x, y")
expr = sy.sin(x) + sy.cos(y)
expr_numpy = sy.lambdify((x, y), expr, modules="numpy")

with open('pickle_test/sample_pickle.pkl', 'wb') as f:
     f.write(cloudpickle.dumps(expr_numpy))

with open('pickle_test/sample_pickle.pkl', 'rb') as f:
    sample_pickle = cloudpickle.load(f)

def evaluate_pickle(x, y):
    result = sample_pickle(x, y)
    return x, y, result

trials = 10
value_x = np.random.uniform(0, 5, trials)
value_y = np.random.uniform(0, 5, trials)

Parallel(n_jobs=4)(delayed(evaluate_pickle)(value_x, value_y) for i in range(trials))
```

I get the following error:

```
joblib.externals.loky.process_executor.BrokenProcessPool: A task has failed to un-serialize. Please ensure that the arguments of the function are all picklable.
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm actually able to run the code without any errors (after changing the path from `pickle_test/sample_pickle.pkl` to `./sample_pickle.pkl`).

Below are the following software versions this code ran successfully on: numpy 1.19.5, sympy 1.7.1, cloudpickle 1.6.0, joblib 1.0.1